# Unable to run app on Xcode with provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, provisioning-profile

I am currently working on an Xcode application to which I was given the provisioning profiles to. I installed a dev and dist profile on Xcode and also was give a certificate to run the app on my phone. Now, when I try to run the application on my phone it gives me this error.

[image]

Similarly, if I try to run the app on a simulator on my M1 Macbook air instead of my phone it gives me this error.

[image]

Comment: "I installed a dev and dist profile on Xcode"  Where and how!?

Comment: I installed the certificates on my keychain and the provisioning profiles I imported through the signing & capabilities section of Xcode,